# Autofs with ghost option not showing wildcard mounts

Tags: linux, automount, autofs

I have this in my autofs map:
`*          -rw server:/share/&`

I also have `--ghost` option enabled in my `/etc/auto.master`. According to the manual and to all resources and examples I found on the web this should work. However, in my case:

`ls /share/` returns nothing.

I would like to profit from the `--ghost` option, so the tab auto-completion and GUI file browsers would show the whole directory listing under `server:/share`.

The OS is Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 and autofs-5.0.4.

How to make the directories under /share appear?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What distribution or kernel version are you running? I don't see anything consistent, but at least some manual pages I see indicate that the wildcard map is not ghosted. This behavior makes some intuitive sense; the wildcard means that any valid pathname is a candidate for mounting, and so the client can't realistically present a choice of mount points without first mounting the directory.

Comment: If you're not averse to direct mounts, a compromise solution might be to automount `server:/share` at `/share`.

Comment: I see. Would you, please, point me to this document? Thanks!

Comment: See, for example, the Ubuntu man page at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/automount.8.html.